# Check if any file in a directory contains words in a constant file

Tags: linux, bash, variables, dictionary, compare

i have a directory with n textfiles. Now, i want to check, if any of these files contains one (or more) words of a constant file.
These files are all dictionarys with a different amount of words. The constant file is a password list, where i want to check these words. The amount of correct hits should be saved in a variable. Also the word should be save (i think as an array) in a variable.

For example: `file1` contains `This is my dictionary`, `file2` contains `And another one`, my password list contains `this is a test for the dictionary and we have no other one`.
The hits from `file1` are `This is dictionary` (`n1=3` words) and from `file2` `and one` (`n2=2` words).

My present code is

```
#!/bin/bash
# program_call passwordlist.txt *.txt
passwordlist="$1"
dictionarys="$*"
for comparison in  $dictionarys; do
  cat $passwordlist $comparison| sort | uniq -d >${comparison}.compare
done
```

One of my biggest problems her is, that i've got a different amount of dictionarys. Maybe 2, maybe 200. Nevermind, all of these has to be checked against the passwordlist and the result (the amound of correct words and the correct word itselfs) has to be saved in his OWN variables. So i think two variable for each dictionary.

Comment: What's wrong with the code that you have? Do you really need to save the results in shell variables, not files? If you want the number of matches, just use `wc -l $comparison.compare`

Comment: You can also use `fgrep -x -f $passwordlist $comparison` to get the lines that match between the files.

Comment: my problem is, that my output is always just one file with all of those results. It would be also okay, when i get just files with my results. i thought, normaly every single $dictionary is saved in comparison, so my output is for example file1.compare, file2.compare, file3.compare and so on. But my output is only .comapare with ALL results. I dont get it. Also, i am only interested in textfiles. so i tried `for comparison in $1dictionarys*.txt; do ` but i've got the same problem. Just one output, but in this case its calles *.txt.compare.

Comment: One problem is that you have the password file in `$dictionarys`, because you forgot to do `shift` before assigning `$*`.

Comment: I think the variables don't contain what you think they should. Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, so you can see an execution trace with all the variables expanded.

Comment: I don't understand your issue about using `$dictionarys*.txt`. The filenames are expanded by the shell when the user invokes the script, you don't need a wildcard inside the script.

Comment: If the user types `*.txt`, you'll only get text files. But if the password file also ends in `.txt`, that will be included.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Now i have all my results saved in separated files, so i can work with them

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. I'm not posting an answer because I have no idea which of my comments addressed the actual problem. I'm not even sure you posted the actual script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# program_call_is /dictionarys/*.txt passwordlist.txt
dictionarys="$1"
shift
passwordlist="$*"
for comparison in  $dictionarys; do
fgrep -x -f $passwordlist $comparison >${comparison}.compare
done
```

Answer (score 1):

another way

```
$ for f in file{1,2}; 
  do echo -n $f": "; 
     grep -iow -f <(tr ' ' '\n' <cons) $f | 
     wc -l; 
  done

file1: 3
file2: 2
```

convert the constants file one word per line, check the dictionary files for word match ignore case and count the matched occurrences.